# How to check it element has attribute or not

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, angular

I have a HTML string, i want to add `id` attribute to all `<form>` tag which don't have `id`.

But I am getting an issue when  tag's child have id.

```
<html>
<body>
  <form class="class1">
    <input id="hello" type="text"/>
  </form>

  <form class="bye">
    bye
    <input type="text"/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In 1st `<form>` it has `<input>` with `id`, that's why it is not adding the id for this element. I just want to check for only `<form>`, but I guess it is checking for entire `<form>` tag

I tried this:

```
const htmlString = `<html>
<body>
  <form class="class1">
    <input id="hello" type="text"/>
  </form>

  <form     class="bye">
    bye
    <input type="text"/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>`

const idPrefix = "MyPrefix";

let modifiedHtmlString = htmlString;

let formIndex = 1;
let startIndex = modifiedHtmlString.indexOf("<form");


while (startIndex !== -1) {
  const endIndex = modifiedHtmlString.indexOf("</form>", startIndex);
  const formTag = modifiedHtmlString.slice(startIndex, endIndex);

  if (!formTag.includes("id=")) {
    const modifiedFormTag = formTag.replace("<form", `<form id="${idPrefix}${formIndex}"`);
    modifiedHtmlString = modifiedHtmlString.replace(formTag, modifiedFormTag);
    formIndex++;
  }

  startIndex = modifiedHtmlString.indexOf("<form", endIndex);
}

console.log(modifiedHtmlString);
```

Comment: I think you'd have much better control of your HTML structure if you used `document.createElement()` and inserting/appending nodes on the go, instead of creating an entire HTML structure inside a template string. That way you could just check the ID of the node you created. I am no expert in react nor angular, though.

Comment: @SigurdMazanti my use case is different, i am taking html input from user, not displaying it. I just want to add `id` to `form` tag

Comment: Parse html first then use`document.querySelector('form').hasAttribute("id")`  to check id attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I assume, you have a string of html elements and not the actual `DOM elements`, You can try the below snippet:

```js
const htmlString = `<html>
<body>
  <form class="class1">
    <input id="hello" type="text"/>
  </form>
  
  <form id="form2" class="class1">
    <input id="hi" type="text"/>
  </form>

  <form     class="bye">
    bye
    <input type="text"/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>`

const div = document.createElement('div')
div.innerHTML = htmlString
Array.from(div.querySelectorAll('form')).forEach((f, i) => {
  if (!f.hasAttribute("id")) {
    f.setAttribute("id", `form_${i+1}`)
  }
})
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(div)
```